# Conflicting trait implementations

Tags: rust, traits

I have the following pair of implementations ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7cb7606b8145269efb4caa2d51ef4715&version=stable)):

```
pub struct Foo<T> {it: T}

impl<T: IntoIterator> From<T> for Foo<T::IntoIter> {
    fn from(x: T) -> Foo<T::IntoIter> {
      Foo { it: x.into_iter() }
    }
}

use std::str::Chars;
impl From<&'static str> for Foo<Chars<'static>> {
    fn from(x: &'static str) -> Foo<Chars<'static>> {
        Foo { it: x.chars() }
    }
}
```

I'm getting a `conflicting implementations error` and I don't understand why. As far as I can tell, the first generic impl cannot cover `From<&'static str>`, since `&str` does *not* implement `IntoIterator`.

Is the compiler not smart enough to figure out this? Is there a *reason* this should not be allowed (say, an esoteric orphan rule)? Is there a way around it?

Comment: *since `&str` does not implement `IntoIterator`* — it doesn't now, but the standard library is free to do so in the future.

Comment: I highly encourage you to search for duplicates next time  — the two I've linked were pretty easy to find for the search term "conflicting implementations of trait from".